# Query several rows from 3 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering how I could do this without using group_concat. Since my reviews are so long the group_concat is maxing out on them so it does not return all the reviews. The only other way I could think of doing it would be to loop the query. Just so you know there are several products and several reviews for each product. Any ideas?

```php
    $this->db->select("product.id,
        product.name as name,
        group_concat(user.name) as user,
        group_concat(rating.overall) as overall,
        group_concat(rating.description SEPARATOR '|') as review");
    $this->db->join('rating', 'rating.idProduct = alcohol.id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('user', 'user.id = rating.idUser', 'LEFT');
    $query = $this->db->get('product');
    return $query->result();
```

output as something like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object (
        [name] => Product
        [reviews] => Array(
                [0]=> (
                        [user] => "cKendrick "
                        [overall] => "1"
                        [Rating] => "lalalalalala review"
                    )
                [1] = >
                    (...
    )

)
[1] => stdClass Object (..
```

UPDATE:

```
"SELECT product.id,
  product.name as name,
  category.permName as category,
  subCategory.permName as subCategory,
  product.permName as permName,
  product.picture as picture,
  user.username as username,
  user.firstName as firstName,
  user.lastName as lastName,
  user.picture as userPicture,
  rating.description as review
FROM (
     SELECT *
     FROM product
     LIMIT ?, 30
) product
LEFT JOIN category
    ON category.id = product.category
LEFT JOIN subCategory
    ON subCategory.id = product.subCategory
LEFT JOIN rating
    ON rating.idAlcohol = product.id
LEFT JOIN user
    ON user.id = rating.idUser
ORDER BY product.lastReview desc"
```

How would I restrict it by its category?

Comment: I am trying to in 1 query get information from 3 tables. The product table, the rating table and the user table. The product table shows several different products while the reviews show several different reviews per product and the user table shows the user who did the review. I am using group_concat because I dont know what else to use. So I guess my question is how would I do this without using group_concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which DBAL are you using? In plain old PHP you could do it like this if you really want to use a single query -

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('dsn', 'user', 'pass');
$sql = "SELECT product.id, product.name, rating.overall, rating.description, user.name AS user  
        FROM (
           SELECT *
           FROM product
           LIMIT 30
        ) product   
        LEFT JOIN rating
            ON product.id = rating.productId   
        LEFT JOIN user
            ON user.id = rating.userId";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$output = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    $output[$row->id]['name'] = $row->name;
    $output[$row->id]['reviews'][] = array('user'        => $row->user,
                                           'overall'     => $row->overall,
                                           'description' => $row->description);
}
```

**UPDATE** - I have moved the product table into a subquery to enable limiting the number of products. Note that any filtering on the products should be added to the subquery not the outer select.

**UPDATE** - updated query based on update to question. As you want to filter products based on category before limiting the result the joins and criteria need to be added to the subquery -

```
SELECT product.id,
    product.name as name,
    product.category,
    product.subCategory,
    product.permName as permName,
    product.picture as picture,
    user.username as username,
    user.firstName as firstName,
    user.lastName as lastName,
    user.picture as userPicture,
    rating.description as review
FROM (
    SELECT
        p.*,
        category.permName AS category,
        subCategory.permName AS subCategory
    FROM product
    LEFT JOIN category
        ON category.id = product.category
    LEFT JOIN subCategory
        ON subCategory.id = product.subCategory
    WHERE category.permName = ?
    LIMIT ?, 30
) product
LEFT JOIN rating
    ON rating.idAlcohol = product.id
LEFT JOIN user
    ON user.id = rating.idUser
ORDER BY product.lastReview desc
```

Comment: What is DBAL? I am sorry I am new at this and am trying to learn. I tried your code and it came back with just an empty array. Also you make it sound like maybe I should do more then 1 query? Would that be smarter to do? I am just trying to figure the best way to get all this content to 1 page.

Comment: DataBase Abstraction Layer. No need to apologise we all have to start somewhere. There is nothing wrong with doing it in one query. It just means that the product.id and product.name fields are replicated for every review on the same product. Probably not a big deal in this case. Did you try checking the query in WorkBench or whatever your preferred db tinkering tool is?

Comment: Would the DBAL then be active record? I just use phpmyadmin to work with the db. as far as the query it works fine there but when I do that there it only shows 1 rating.overall and 1 rating description and 1 user. when it should be showing anywhere from 1 to 10 depending on the product.

Comment: The query will return every product with its associated ratings and raters unless you have modified it. Are you adding a GROUP BY clause or an aggregate function in the field list?

Comment: Great got it working, I am not really sure though what is going on. Is this looping through the mysql query or is this just taking the results from the query and rearranging it? Again sorry if this is a stupid question I just really want to understand the fundamentals here

Comment: It is just iterating over the resultset assigning the values to an array in a similar format to that specified in your question. Play with it using die and print_r and you should soon be able to understand the approach.

Comment: ok thanks, I have one other question I hope you can help me with. I want to be able to limit the amount of products show to 30 but using `LIMIT 30` in the query limits it to show only 30 reviews. Is there a way I can limit it by product and not reviews in the query?

Comment: awesome I have 1 more question, I am trying to use the `WHERE user.user LIKE 'username'`in my query but if I put it after the join it does not display all the info and if I use it in the sub query I cant use the actual name I have to use the identifier. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Do you want to restrict it so that it only shows ratings from a given user?

Comment: Basically I wanna use the name of the joined user to restrict the product

Comment: How are you going to filter products based on the user? Is it show you only show the products that have been reviewed by the user?

Comment: I have updated above with my new sql query. I am trying to limit it based on its category

Answer (score 0):

Here are my assumptions:

You want to get all the products with associated ratings. You want to know who wrote which review.

```
 select product.id, product.name, rating.overall, rating.description, user.name 
from product 
left join rating on product.id = rating.productId 
left join on user.id=rating.userId;
```

If this is not what you want, edit your post and show a few rows of what you are looking for would look like.

Comment: I have edit the post. Output I would like to be something like my edit but if there is another way of doing this in 1 query I am open to it. The joins wont work because there are multiple entries for rating.overall, rating.description, user.name